# Error when trying to create a record of salesorderdetail

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-365, dynamics-crm-365, dynamics-crm-webapi

I am trying to create a record of `salesorderdetail` and got an error:

```
{
   "error":
   {
      "code":"0x80040216",
      "message":"An unexpected error occurred.",
      "innererror":
      {
         "message":"An unexpected error occurred.",
         "type":"System.ServiceModel.FaultException`1[[Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.OrganizationServiceFault, Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk, Version=9.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35]]",
         "stacktrace":"   at Microsoft.Crm.Extensibility.OrganizationSdkServiceInternal.CreateInternal(Entity entity, CorrelationToken correlationToken, CallerOriginToken callerOriginToken, WebServiceType serviceType, Boolean checkAdminMode, Dictionary`2 optionalParameters)\r\n   at Microsoft.Crm.Extensibility.OData.CrmODataExecutionContext.CreateOrganizationResponse(Entity entity)\r\n   at Microsoft.Crm.Extensibility.OData.CrmODataServiceDataProvider.CreateEdmEntity(CrmODataExecutionContext context, String edmEntityName, EdmEntityObject entityObject, Boolean isUpsert)\r\n   at Microsoft.Crm.Extensibility.OData.EntityController.PostEntitySetImplementation(String& entitySetName, EdmEntityObject entityObject)\r\n   at Microsoft.PowerApps.CoreFramework.ActivityLoggerExtensions.Execute[TResult](ILogger logger, EventId eventId, ActivityType activityType, Func`1 func)\r\n   at Microsoft.Xrm.Telemetry.XrmTelemetryExtensions.Execute[TResult](ILogger logger, XrmTelemetryActivityType activityType, Func`1 func)\r\n   at lambda_method(Closure , Object , Object[] )\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ActionExecutor.<>c__DisplayClass10.<GetExecutor>b__9(Object instance, Object[] methodParameters)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ExecuteAsync(HttpControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 arguments, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ApiControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionAsyncCore>d__0.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ActionFilterResult.<ExecuteAsync>d__2.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.<SendAsync>d__1.MoveNext()"
      }
   }
}
```

My request:

```
    POST [Organization URI]/api/data/v9.0/salesorderdetails
    Accept: application/json
    OData-MaxVersion: 4.0
    OData-Version: 4.0
    Authorization: Bearer *key*   
    Prefer: return=representation
    Content-Type: application/json;IEEE754Compatible=true

    {
         "productname":"Test"
    }
```

My guess is the error occurred because my `salesorderdetail` doesn't have `salesorderid`? If so, any way to create `salesorderdetail` alone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No way. No parent no child. Without sales order why someone need sales order details?

[Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/developer/entities/salesorderdetail#BKMK_SalesOrderId) says `salesorderid` is `SystemRequired`.

**Update**:
In fact `salesorderid` is the only required value to create `salesorderdetails` (Order Product) record. I tested the below snippet in CRM Rest builder.

```
var entity = {};
entity["salesorderid@odata.bind"] = "/salesorders(B4B625A1-3789-E811-A967-000D3A1A9407)";

var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.open("POST", Xrm.Page.context.getClientUrl() + "/api/data/v8.2/salesorderdetails", true);
req.setRequestHeader("OData-MaxVersion", "4.0");
req.setRequestHeader("OData-Version", "4.0");
req.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
req.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
req.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState === 4) {
        req.onreadystatechange = null;
        if (this.status === 204) {
            var uri = this.getResponseHeader("OData-EntityId");
            var regExp = /\(([^)]+)\)/;
            var matches = regExp.exec(uri);
            var newEntityId = matches[1];
        } else {
            Xrm.Utility.alertDialog(this.statusText);
        }
    }
};
req.send(JSON.stringify(entity));
```

Comment: I have a list of records of multiple entities, I need to insert/update them all. My solution is insert/update all entities then update all associations between them.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem with Quotes. Indeed, you always need the SalesOrderId to create a SalesOrderDetail. I think you will also need the productId. Unless you complete the fields to make it an inline product (outside of catalog).